# SQlite primary key field name & CursorAdapter subclasses

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

Why do `CursorAdapter` subclasses requires the primary key to be necessarily `_id` ?

Isn't there a method to override, or something like that, to change this behaviour ?

I have read this trick many times, and I am aware of that ... I just want to understand better !
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does CursorAdapter subclasses requires the primary key to be necessarily _id ?

It turns around and provides that value in various places, such as the `long id` value in `getView()`.

> Isn't there a method to override, or something like that, to change this behaviour ?

No, sorry. If you do not have a suitable column, just add `ROWID AS _ID` to your list of columns to return in `rawQuery()`:

```
SELECT ROWID AS _id, foo, bar FROM really_important_table ORDER BY foo;
```

`ROWID` is automatically added to all SQLite tables by default, and is a unique integer, which fits the `_id` requirements nicely.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Tell me, Is there a way to avoid this, without using aliases ! It's an ***ugly*** behaviour, I don't like to always use aliases, or rename my column name !!

Comment: @mansoulx: "Is there a way to avoid this, without using aliases" -- don't use `CursorAdapter`. Write your own `Adapter` that can work with a `Cursor` and does not require `_id`.

Comment: facing such a dilemma, I prefer using `_id`, instead of doing all the stuff myself ! Thanks a lot