# How to deal with error column '_id' does not exist in Android custom Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have a table with column _id and it used normally in several queries I did another query with a new custom cursor adapter like the following

```
public class TimeOutCAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
View retView;
Context context;
Cursor cur;
private DBHelper mHelper;
public TimeOutCAdapter(Context context, Cursor c)
{
    super(context, c);
    this.context =context;
    this.cur =c;
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeout_item, parent, false);
    return retView;
}
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    List<TextView> txtStatsTimeout;
    final int[] statsTimeout =
            {
                   R.id.txtTimeOut1,R.id.txtTimeOut2,R.id.txtTimeOut3,R.id.txtTimeOut4,R.id.txtTimeOut5,R.id.txtTimeOut6,R.id.txtTimeOut7,
                   R.id.txtTimeOut8,R.id.txtTimeOut9,R.id.txtTimeOut10,R.id.txtTimeOut11,R.id.txtTimeOut12
            };
    txtStatsTimeout = new ArrayList<TextView>(); //List with textviews
    for (int id : statsTimeout) {
        TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(id);
        txtStatsTimeout.add(txtView);
    }
   view.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeOut1);

    textViewName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gameroster_name")));

    for(int i=0;i<txtStatsTimeout.size();i++)
    {
        txtStatsTimeout.get(i).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(i))));
    }
    view.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
}
```

}

I get the error in the class declaration on super(context,c)

Comment: you need to add it the _id column to your query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23068296/115145

Comment: I have done the above already

Answer (score 0):

Yes the above are correct but we should be careful from which table we get the _id so I did customer_id AS _id  as mentioned and not just an _id